# Batch: Escaping current directory within a FOR iterator command

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm having a heck of a time getting this to escape correctly, I am on Windows 7, and created a batch file that uses the current directory. The current directory usually will have spaces in it, so it has to be escaped in double quotes.

I have a folder my batch file runs inside, and the folder contains sub-directories, so I want to reference other files within those sub-folders:

```
echo "%~dp0"
set rootDir=%~dp0%Support\Command.exe
set _serial_cmd="%rootDir%
echo %_serial_cmd%

FOR /f "tokens=4 delims=(COM)]" %%G IN ('%_serial_cmd% ^|findstr /R /C:"Standard COM Port"') DO SET AVRSERIALPORT=COM%%G
```

`echo %_serial_cmd%` prints out fine, but the variable reference %_serial_cmd% in the FOR statement does not like the quotes, or stops reading after the first space in the directory path.

Comment: Support is a sub-directory within the main folder the batch file runs inside

Comment: 1st what is your question? 2nd difficult to help without knowing what your `command.exe` output looks like. 3rd your `delims=` is definitely wrong, it will split input at all distinct delims characters to tokens. 4th you have unbalanced double quotes in `set _serial_cmd="%rootDir%`